# XeLaTeX ignores \fontsize command in preamble

Tags: xetex, fontsize, fontspec

Consider the following LaTeX manuscript:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times}
\begin{document}
    \fontsize{50}{50}\selectfont
    Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

When processed with `xelatex`, it renders the text as follows. In particular, the font size is `50pt`, as expected:

[image: Big size]

If I now move the `\fontsize...\selectfont` commands to the preamble, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times}
\fontsize{50}{50}\selectfont
\begin{document}
    Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

`xelatex` ignores the size specifications, and the text renders small:

[image: Small size]

Why is this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken begin document contains a normalize declaration to ensure fonts gave been setup correctly.

Comment: `\begin{document}` calls for `\normalsize` which negates your font size setting. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152085/117534

Comment: @daleif: So there's no general way of setting the default font size in the preamble?

Comment: @EvanAad try: \AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{50}{50}\selectfont}

Comment: Use a class that supports custom font sizes and make a custom clo file.

Comment: @daleif: Could you give an example for such a class, please?

Comment: Memoir supports it and I'm guessing KOMA classes have something similar. Might not be well described in the manuals. Why would you even have a 50pt font set from the preamble?

Comment: @daleif: Mostly for experimentation purposes, but it Just seems cleaner to set it in the preamble.

Comment: I've never seen others try to do it that way, most just do that kind of experiments in the doc it self. Saves having to write your own clo file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When latex or xelatex reads \begin{document} it changes fontsize back to \normalsize... Try the next code to see it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{50}{50}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
   Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

The problem is that if you use the above command, then \Large, \small etc has also to be changed. So, a better solution is to make the command be read at begin of document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{50}{50}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
   Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

**Edit: (the below is not true)**
This way it will give you the desired results even if you start a section, or use \Large etc

Unfortunately you have to change manually every size:

See here: [Change font size of \Large etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24616/change-font-size-of-large-etc)

Answer (score 5):

Setting up a new "normal" font size involves also changing \Large, \small and some other commands and also spacings (e.g. for lists). Check size10.clo (loaded by your document) or scrsize11.clo (loaded by mine) to get an idea what is involved. There exist a number of .clo-files for other fontsizes, but if you want to change to an arbitrary fontsize you should better use a class like scrartcl from the KOMA-bundle:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=50pt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\begin{document}
Test, \Large large, \tiny tiny
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is just to print a line with big font size, just do the declaration when you want to output the line. I see no real advantage in issuing the declaration in the preamble. There's always

```
\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{50}{50}\selectfont}
```

that will do.

For the more general problem of defining a larger base font size, since you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, there is a simple (or perhaps simplistic) solution to the fact that LaTeX issues `\normalsize` at begin document. Note you need to also set the sans and mono font at the same scale, if you use them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[Scale=5]
\linespread{5}

\begin{document}

\section{Humongous}

Some text at 50pt size.
Some text at 50pt size.
Some text at 50pt size.
Some text at 50pt size.
Some text at 50pt size.
Some text at 50pt size.
Some text at 50pt size.
Some text at 50pt size.
Some text at 50pt size.
Some text at 50pt size.
Some text at 50pt size.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I add the info window

[image]

Comment: The "scale" option is less than ideal, since in the case of outline fonts (which is what I was interested in yesterday when I wrote this post), it pumps up the outline's line width relative to a font that is the same size, but not scaled.

Comment: @EvanAad [Click on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZiNb.png): one line uses `\fontsize{50}{50}`, the other one the font at natural size, but defined with `Scale=5`. I won't tell which is which: can you guess?

Comment: No, I can't. Sorry. I thought fontspec's `Scale` was similar to PGF's canvas scale, which changes line widths. But then when you tell `fontspec` to scale a font by `x` amount, relative to what does it scale it? Can you specify the normal size relative to which the scaling should take place?

Comment: @EvanAad Unless the font has optical sizes, such as Latin Modern, it is designed at a single size.

Comment: Is there a way to tell what this size is?

Comment: @EvanAad It should be in the font information. Usually 10pt (or 10bp)

Comment: What do you mean by "font information"? The .ttf file?

Comment: @EvanAad Where, otherwise?

Comment: I've asked in a font designers forum, and I was told physical font size is not normally stored in .ttf files.

Comment: @EvanAad OpenType fonts usually have the information.

Comment: I was told that a typeface is implemented based on abstract length units called upm (units per em) that have no inherent physical interpretation. The font file (.ttf or what have you) doesn't provide a default physical font size. The font size would be set by the document class or by the user by issuing `\fontsize` commands.

Comment: @EvanAad You were told wrong. If I do `otfinfo -z /Library/Fonts/ebgaramond/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf`, the output is `design size 12 pt, size range (9.5 pt, 120 pt], subfamily ID 1, subfamily name Regular`